# add name= required with js (eForm Modx)

Tags: javascript, validation, modx

I use Modx eForm for my form.

**My problem, I need to add :required to a couple of input fields but only when the checkbox is unchecked!**

I have fields like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Last name" id="deliver_lastname" name="deliver_lastname:required" class="[[!+fi.error.deliver_lastname:notempty=`error`]]" />
```

:required needs to be set after unchecking the checkbox.

I have a checkbox to default hide some fields.

```
<p id="shiptobilling" class="form-row">
Same as billing address <input type="checkbox" onclick="SetBilling(this.checked);" checked="checked" /> 
</p>
```

A little script to hide the div with fields into it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function SetBilling(checked) {
    if (checked) {document.getElementById('deliveryaddres').style.display="none";}
    else {document.getElementById('deliveryaddres').style.display="block";}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can be made easier - let deliveryaddres will always be required, and when checkbox is checked just let the value of the field is synchronized with billingaddres.

Needed javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetBilling() {
        var deliveryaddres = document.getElementById('deliveryaddres');
        var billingaddres = document.getElementById('billingaddres');
        var shiptobilling = document.getElementById('shiptobilling').getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
        if (shiptobilling.checked) {
            deliveryaddres.value = billingaddres.value;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Needed events "onclick" and "onchange" on inputs:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="deliveryaddres" onclick="SetBilling();" /> 

<input type="text" id="billingaddres" onchange="SetBilling();" />
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay (queensday). I doubt this is working.
All I need is to add this :required behind the name= like here:
 name="deliver_lastname:required" so when the checkbox isn't checked the billing fields show and they are required!

My total code here; http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=62Ni9ABJ

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=26dzK8hE

it has the required field into it, hmmm I wish I was a coder more that designer sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

Add something like

```
document.getElementById("deliver_lastname").required = true;
```

Comment: Hi, I don't need a class required but name="blabla:required"

Comment: The above code doesn't set a class required, it actually makes the field required in HTML5 compliant browsers.